# Google Adsense ads are not shown in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, adsense

The Adsense ads on one of my sites are shown in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox.

What can I do to get this solved: Every visitor should see the Adsense Ads in Firefox. Thank you.

Comment: you are gonna have to be a little more specific

Comment: No Adsense Ad is shown. Why? Does Firefox has an adblocker?

Comment: There could literally be thousands of reasons. With the information you've provided there is no way for anyone to know what's wrong.

Comment: Tell me 5 reason, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox contains a [tracking protection](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Tracking_protection) feature. When it is on, Firefox does not connect to servers known to correlate visitors' browsing activity across domains. By default, tracking protection is on in Private Browsing windows and off elsewhere. Some extensions, such as Ghostery and Disconnect, also block connections to tracking servers.

Major ad networks and ad exchanges, such as Google AdSense/AdWords and DoubleClick, track viewers' behavior from one site to another in order to show ads deemed [more relevant](https://www.networkadvertising.org/understanding-online-advertising/how-does-it-benefit-me) to each viewer, such as [retargeting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_retargeting). To show ads to tracking blocker users, you'll need to take sponsorship orders directly from advertisers and host the ads yourself. [Daring Fireball has done this](https://daringfireball.net/2017/07/df_display_ads), and its solution doesn't even need JavaScript.

If you are hosting your own site's ads, and they still aren't appearing in Firefox, look in [Firefox's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) and feel free to provide details.